# Join subquery to update a table in PgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update an existing Table Maintable with a subquery that produces a table with two columns (subtype and id). The subquery works fine individually. But I cannot join the output of the subquery to update my table.

The code I used is

```
WITH subquery AS (Select distinct on (x.cluster_id) x.cluster_id, y.subtype
from datatable1 x
LEFT JOIN datatable y  ON x.unique_id=y.unique_id
order by cluster_id, start_time desc)

Update Maintable
Set subtype= subquery.subtype from subquery
where Maintable.cluster_id = subquery.cluster_id
```

The error is column "subtype" of relation "Maintable" does not exist

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use dbfilddle(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bbebf7efe9f01901d41d4013bf96b4c) create some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Update Maintable um Set subtype= subquery.subtype from  Maintable m  
inner join subquery on m.cluster_id = subquery.cluster_id 
where m.unique_id=um.unique_id // Assume that unique_id is the Primay key of Maintable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).